# Best way to load a jdbc connection string from a file so its not hard-coded into the program?

Tags: java, mysql, variables, jdbc

I tried creating a new class with a method that set the connection strings to public static variables via a properties file using the input filestream.

then the idea was that in: `DriverManager.getConnection(<the global variable containing the connection string>)`

However I'm presented with a java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tr" error.

I find this really strange because the variable doesnt work, but when i `System.output.println(variable)` it, and copy the output in console into the `DriverManager.getConnection(>Paste here<)` it works fine.

Could someone possibly answer the question and explain to me why this happens?

Thanks.

Comment: Does you variable in the properties file perchance contain quotes?

Comment: Does it work when you enter the connection string hard-coded? if no you miss the jdbc driver lib (jar)

Comment: It works when i hard-code the connection string, and yes @BoristheSpider it does have quotes.
eg: 
dburl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tr"

Comment: Please post the representative contents of your properties file.

Answer (score 2):

In a Java properties file, the key is before an `=` and the value is after.

**Everything** after the `=` is the value.

```
dburl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tr
```

i.e. No quotes.

Answer (score 0):

you should use property value after using calling trim so that extra space can be removed.....